# jQuery fade in goes way faster than fade out?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have an image which I'd like to fade in and out.

```
$("#img").animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 1000 );


$("#img").animate({
    opacity: 100
}, 1000 );
```

Even though the timer is set to 1000 milleseconds for both, fading in happens much faster.
Why is this happening?

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G3KtZ/

Comment: $("#img").fadeToggle("slow");​​​​

Comment: @Learner -- what you are proposing is NOT equivalent to what the user is attempting to do because all of jQuery's various "fade" methods set "display:none" at the end rather than just affecting the opacity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your "fade in" animate function, you are setting the opacity to 100. It should simply be set to 1. Opacity in CSS is from 0 to 1, and therefore its the same in JavaScript (since you are using Javascript to modify the CSS).

So here's what happens. jQuery animates the opacity from 0 to 100 over the course of 1000ms. But as soon as the opacity hits 1 (after only 10ms), the opacity is full.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/G3KtZ/3/

Answer (score 2):

Opacity is measured between 0 and 1, change the second part of your code to:

```
$("#img").animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 1000 );
```

And it's fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Set the opacity to 1 instead of 100. 
Higher values than 1 work in CSS, but make no sense. Full opacity is 1,  invisible means 0.

Answer (score 2):

Opacity takes values between 0 and 1, not 0 and 100. That causes the maximum value (1) to be at 1% of the fade in animation.

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
$("#img").animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 1000 );
```

not 100.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` method:

```
$("#img").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G3KtZ/4/